# Cannot set toolbar via setActionBar (Android)

Tags: java, android, toolbar

Here is my toolbar layout.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

And code to fetch it.

```
Toolbar toolbar;
toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById( R.id.my_toolbar)
setActionBar(toolbar)
```

Comment: Try using setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `setSupportActionBar (toolbar)` instead of `setActionBar(toolbar)`.
Should work that way.